# Change a row header based on query results without doing multiple queries

Tags: php, mysql, row

I just can't logically think how to do this without doing multiple queries, which I'd like to avoid if possible. I have a mysql table set up like this.

```
+------+----------+--------------+--------------+
| Id   | Opponent | Game Date    | Playoffs     |
+------+----------+--------------+--------------+
| 1    | Chicago  | 2020-08-20   | First Round  |
| 2    | Chicago  | 2020-08-22   | First Round  |
| 3    | Chicago  | 2020-08-24   | First Round  |
| 4    | Chicago  | 2020-08-26   | First Round  |
| 5    | Dallas   | 2020-08-28   | Second Round |
| 6    | Dallas   | 2020-08-30   | Second Round |
| 7    | Dallas   | 2020-09-01   | Second Round |
+------+----------+--------------+--------------+
```

What I want to do is pull the results so I can display them in a table like this.

```
+------+-------------------+----------------+
| Game |     Opponent      |    Date        |
+-------------------------------------------+
|        Playoff Round: First Round         | 
+-------------------------------------------+
| 1    |     Chicago       |  2020-08-20    |
+------+-------------------+----------------+
| 2    |     Chicago       |  2020-08-22    |
+------+-------------------+----------------+
| 3    |     Chicago       |  2020-08-24    |
+------+-------------------+----------------+
| 4    |     Chicago       |  2020-08-26    |
+-------------------------------------------+
|        Playoff Round: Second Round        | 
+-------------------------------------------+
| 5    |     Dallas        |  2020-08-28    |
+------+-------------------+----------------+
| 6    |     Dallas        |  2020-08-30    |
+------+-------------------+----------------+
| 7    |     Dallas        |  2020-09-01    |
+------+-------------------+----------------+
```

I just can't quite think how to do it without running separate queries on each round.  I'd rather not have to do it that way, I think it's probably unnecessary. Thanks!

Comment: Such presentation concern should probably be handled on application siderather that in the database. A SQL query generates a fixed list of columns, there is feature that "merges" adjacent columns in a given row, as in a spreadsheet for example.

Comment: SQL query always generates a full table list but for this format, you should write two queries one for round and second for table data of round

Comment: Of course you may create a query which removes `Playoffs` column but adds extra rows with group value - but in this extra row the value will be assigned to one of columns (`Opponent` - because another columns have different data type). Then your client may check the row, and expand `Opponent` value to whole row if, for example, `id AS Game` contains NULL.

Comment: Thanks Akina that's an interesting idea!

Comment: As mentioned, consider handling issues of data display in application code

Comment: All this needs is a simple, one-level _control break_ implmentation.

Comment: Well I went with the easiest way I could do and that was separate queries.  In the end it works fine, maybe it's a little bit of a resource hog, but it works.  If you're interested in the final product, go to this page and look at the bottom where the playoffs are, you can actually see what I wanted to do. https://www.lakerstats.com/season-schedule/?seasonid=1920